# Unable to fetch data from Cassandra using spark (java)

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to Cassandra and Spark and trying to fetch data from DB using spark.
I am using Java for this purpose.
Problem is that there are no exceptions thrown or error occurred but still I am not able to get the data. Find my code below -

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
    sparkConf.setAppName("Spark-Cassandra Integration");
    sparkConf.setMaster("local[4]");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "stagingHost22");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042");

    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms", "5000");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms", "200000");


    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    String keySpaceName = "testKeySpace";
    String tableName = "testTable";

    CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(javaSparkContext).cassandraTable(keySpaceName, tableName);

    final ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();
    JavaRDD<String> userRDD = cassandraRDD.map(new Function<CassandraRow, String>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -165799649937652815L;


        public String call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Inside RDD call");
            dataList.add(row);
            return "test";
        }
    });
    System.out.println( "data Size -" + dataList.size());
```

Cassandra and spark maven dependencies are -

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is sure that stagingHost22 host has the cassandra data with keyspace - testKeySpace and table name - testTable. Find below query output -

> cqlsh:testKeySpace> select count(*) from testTable;
>
> ### count
>
> 34
>
> (1 rows)

Can Anybody please suggest what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Warm regards,

Vibhav

Answer (score 3):

Your current code does not perform any Spark action. Therefore no data is loaded.

See the Spark documentation to understand the difference between transformations and actions in Spark:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations

Furthermore adding CassandraRows to a ArrayList isn't something that is usally necessary when using the Cassandra connector. I would suggest to implement a simple select first (following the Spark-Cassandra-Connector documentation). If this is working you can extend this code as needed.

Check the following links on samples how to load data using the connector:

- https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md
- https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md